# Hola, me podrian explicar como se representan estas ecuaciones en codigo de java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema ya que en el codigo que estoy escribiendo ce java no logro representar estas ecuaciones a codigo, por enden si alguien podria explicarme se lo agradeceria mucho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola David, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes, y adjuntes tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, sería algo como esto:

```
double a = ( sqrt( pow( x, 5 ) - 6 )) / 4;

double b = pow( x, y ) - pow( 6, x );

double c = 4 * cos( z / 5 ) - sin( pow( x, 2 ));

double d = pow( x, 4 ) - sqrt( 6 * x - pow( y, 3 ));

double e =  1 / ( y - 1 / ( x - pow( 2, y )));

double f = 7 * ( cos( sqrt( 5 - sin( sqrt( 3 * x - 4 )))));
```

Resumen de los métodos del lenguaje:

obtener la raiz cuadrada de un número:

```
int X = 47;
double raiz = sqrt( X );
```

obtener el valor de un número elevado al cuadrado:

```
double cuadrado = pow( X, 2 );
```

En el caso de necesitar elevar el número a otro exponente, se puede reemplazar, por ejemplo para elevarlo al cubo usamos:

```
double cubo = pow( X, 3 );
```

Obtener el coseno de un ángulo:

```
double coseno = cos( X );
```

Obtener el seno de un ángulo:

```
double coseno = cos( X );
```

En el caso del seno y del coseno, cabe aclarar que estos métodos funcionan con una entrada en ***radianes***, si se necesita usar ***grados***, se deben convertir previamente a radianes de la siguiente manera:

```
double anguloEnGrados = X;

double anguloEnRadianes = toRadians( x );

double anguloEnGrados = toDegrees( anguloEnRadianes );
```

Todos estos métodos pertenecen a la clase ***Math***, por lo que es necesario importarlos con:

import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static java.lang.Math.toDegrees;
import static java.lang.Math.toRadians;

Comment: @Bryro, gracias por la corrección!!

Comment: La respuesta no solo responde un ejercicio. si no que es mala, porque no explica absolutamente nada, es solo codigo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias por la observación... corregido.

Comment: @David, fijate que hice una corrección, los métodos de **java** que trabajan con ángulos, solo funcionan con radianes, por lo que hay que convertirlos